# GSuite Reseller Api

Tags: java, google-workspace

Is their anyway we can exrecise G-suite Reseller api without Reseller agreement.
I have G-suite account,activated G-suite reseller api in G-Suite could console. But when I try executing reseller Api, I get permission denied. 
Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is their anyway we can exrecise G-suite Reseller api without Reseller agreement.

No. As stated in the documentation:

> [Usage of the reseller tools console and Reseller API requires a fully executed and signed reseller contract.](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/prerequisites)

---

> But when I try executing reseller Api, I get permission denied.

The reseller tools and reseller API are for resellers. If you want to use them, you must become a reseller.